# Specify a nested model with and without correlated slope and intercept?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lme4-nlme, lavaan

I have a psychotherapy data set that has a nested structure - patients nested within therapists.  I'm interested in fitting a model that predicts patients' outcome (a level 1 patient variable) from the length of treatment.  In 'lmer' it would be something like this:

mod1 <- lmer(effect.size ~ Tx.length + (1|Therapist), data = data)

I am interested in allowing the intercept and slope to correlate in one model but not in the other.  I'm interested in whether the random intercept X slope correlation is different from zero.

Do I need to use 'lavaan' to fit this model?  Are there straightforward ways to specify the nesting of patients within therapists?

Comment: I don't understand the reason you give for wanting to use `lavaan` over `lmer`. You can't estimate the two models (one where the intercept and slope are correlated and one where they're not) with `lmer`?

Comment: Thanks, Patrick.  I'd much prefer lmer if possible.  How does one coerce the random intercept X slope correlation to zero in lmer?  And then can you simply compare the models using anova( ) as in other instances of nested models?

Answer (score 4):

You specify in the comments that your actual interest is just in running models that do and don't include a correlation between the random intercept and slope, using `lmer()` if possible and lavaan if needed. You can make random effects independent (not correlated) with `lme4::lmer()`:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (0 + Days | Subject) + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm3 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days || Subject), sleepstudy)
```

In this example (using the `sleepstudy` dataset in the lme4 package), `fm1` allows a correlation between the random slope and intercept, since they're specified together. The second model, `fm2`, is very similar, but it specifies the random effects separately, which tells `lme4` that they should be independent (`fm3` will work exactly the same as `fm2`, just written in shorthand).